# Auto completion for cmder?

Tags: cmder

Okay I want a linux-like auto completion for windows. I use cmder as console emulator.

I've found [Clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) which seems to do a pretty good job. 
When I inject the exe it just won't work. When I install it with the setup or with the `cmder` settings it *destroys* the default cmder tab, the lambda symbol will be presented as `{lambda}` etc.

Is there a working way to inject clink into cmder? Or is there a working project to extend cmder with auto completion?

Answer (score 1):

Clink *is* distributed with cmder. You do not neet to "install" it. Just run installed cmder and enjoy.

[image: clink in ConEmu]